# Filter rel attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several rel attributes on my page, I'd like to filter only the attributes `rel="attachment`

but the problem is that each `rel=attachment` attribute has some more `rel`, e.g.:

```
rel="attachment wp-att-53"
rel="attachment wp-att-54"
rel="attachment wp-att-55"
```

there are other names on the page for the `rel` attribute e.g:

```
rel="otherRel"
```

the following code is copying all rel attribute:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[rel]').appendTo('.two');
});
```

how do I filter only the attributes `rel=attachment`?

please see jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/strfcL0c/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
$('a[rel^="attachment wp"]').appendTo('.two');
```

Comment: That won't match any of the elements shown.... the attribute value is not equal as suggested by the selector

Comment: @LiroyLeshed.com thanks, How do I do that where the pictures were before there is not an empty space?

Comment: use the method from the other question to remove the original DOM elements :)

Comment: @LiroyLeshed.com I have an effect that when scrolling the page down the images appear from the left or right. But with this code the scrooling effect is not working properly. The scrolling goes beyond the image and only after it overrides the image that the effect appears

Comment: with your code or code of @Roamer-1888 the result is the same

Comment: send a link? however, i don't think it's related to this question

Comment: I do not have a link, it's on localhost, but thanks I'll try to find a solution to this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this `$('a[rel^=attachment]')`

`^=` stands for *starts with* so the resulting list will contain only elements that have a `rel` property of which value starts with `attachment`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Just one more question, how do I make where the images were previously not have an empty space?

Comment: @Gislef I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to reverse the process ?

Comment: `appendTo` changes all `<a>` content including the images to another location. But in the place that was before is an empty space. I wish I did not leave this empty space